# using Table variable with sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that contain a table variable:

```
DECLARE @Selects    XML ;
SET @Selects='<Selects><Select><Q_ID>1</Q_ID><Q_DESC>nima1</Q_DESC></Select><Select><Q_ID>2</Q_ID><Q_DESC>nima2</Q_DESC></Select><Select><Q_ID>3</Q_ID><Q_DESC>nima3</Q_DESC></Select></Selects>'

DECLARE @QuestionID     NVARCHAR(10);
SET @QuestionID='a5';

DECLARE @TblSelect  TABLE 
(
    Q_ID            INT,
    Q_DESC          NVARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO @TblSelect
(
    Q_ID,Q_DESC
)
SELECT  Q_Select.value('(Q_ID)[1]', 'int') AS 'Q_ID',
        Q_Select.value('(Q_DESC)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') AS 'Q_DESC'
FROM    @Selects.nodes('/Selects/Select') AS AllSelects(Q_Select) 

DECLARE @Query      NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @Query=N'SELECT Q_ID,COUNT(Q_ID) FROM @TblSelect LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbase tb ON @TblSelect.Q_ID = @Col_Select group by Q_ID';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query,@TblSelect,@Col_Select
```

How I can pass the table variable to my query?

Comment: I came here because I wanted to *insert* dynamic SQL into a table variable, but in that case, the reference can just be put in front: `INSERT INTO @TabVar EXEC sp_executesql …`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here's an example of how to pass a table-valued parameter to `sp_executesql`.  The variable has to be passed `readonly`:

```
if exists (select * from sys.types where name = 'TestTableType')
    drop type TestTableType

create type TestTableType as table (id int)
go
declare @t TestTableType
insert @t select 6*7

exec sp_executesql N'select * from @var', N'@var TestTableType readonly', @t
```

This prints the [Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).

Comment: you mean that there is no way to pass Table variable?Is this better than us temprory table?

Comment: @Nima: You can pass a table variable, and in fact, this example does so.  But the table variable must have a named type.  So it has to be `declare @t TestTableType` (named type) and not `declare @t (id int)` (anonymous type)

Comment: Readonly means: NO to the question. Basically,executesql and table type can only be used as read-only.

Answer (score 2):

Try Table Type

```
DECLARE @Selects    XML ;
    SET @Selects='<Selects><Select><Q_ID>1</Q_ID><Q_DESC>nima1</Q_DESC></Select><Select><Q_ID>2</Q_ID><Q_DESC>nima2</Q_DESC></Select><Select><Q_ID>3</Q_ID><Q_DESC>nima3</Q_DESC></Select></Selects>'

    DECLARE @QuestionID     NVARCHAR(10);
    SET @QuestionID='a5';

    DECLARE TYPE TblSelect  AS TABLE 
    (
        Q_ID            INT,
        Q_DESC          NVARCHAR(500)
    )

    /* Declare a variable that references the type. */
    DECLARE @TblSelect 
    AS TblSelect ;

    INSERT INTO @TblSelect 
    (
        Q_ID,Q_DESC
    )

    SELECT  Q_Select.value('(Q_ID)[1]', 'int') AS 'Q_ID',
            Q_Select.value('(Q_DESC)[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') AS 'Q_DESC'
    FROM    @Selects.nodes('/Selects/Select') AS AllSelects(Q_Select) 

    DECLARE @Query      NVARCHAR(4000);
    SET @Query=N'SELECT Q_ID,COUNT(Q_ID) FROM @TblSelect LEFT OUTER JOIN tblbase tb ON @TblSelect.Q_ID = @Col_Select group by Q_ID';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query,@TblSelect,@Col_Select
```

Comment: I got this Error: `Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
'TblSelect' is not a recognized CURSOR option` and I don't know hat is wrong with my `@Col_Select` I got error for it too

Comment: see this link for more referance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Comment: `DECLARE TYPE TblSelect  AS TABLE`
should be
`CREATE TYPE TblSelect  AS TABLE`