# Transpose or pivot SQL @Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure that uses the dynamic input parameter `@Instring VarChar = '1,2,3,4'`. This procedure populates `@RetTable` like this:

```
myDates     myReturns   ID
2012-05-02  0.020       1
2012-05-03  -0.017      1
2012-05-04  -0.026      1
2012-05-02  0.009       2
2012-05-03  0.004       2
2012-05-04  -0.003      2
2012-05-02  -0.003      3
2012-05-03  -0.005      3
2012-05-04  -0.003      3
2012-05-02  0.004       4
2012-05-03  0.010       4
2012-05-04  -0.021      4
```

I then want to pivot or transpose `@RetTable` by the `ID` column to look like this:

```
myDates      1        2       3       4
2012-05-02  0.020   0.009   -0.003  0.004
2012-05-03  -0.017  0.004   -0.005  0.010
2012-05-04  -0.026  -0.003  -0.003  -0.021
```

this is the code I have thus far:

```
Select * From @ReturnsTable
Pivot(Max(myReturns) For [ID] In ([1],[2],[3],[4])) As myPTable
```

This part of code:

```
([1],[2],[3],[4]))
```

I want to replace with/to reference `@InString` in order to have a dynamic procedure.  I have tried various dynamic sql posts on SO but run into issues with every other attempt.  Any ideas?

EDIT:

In answer to @bluefeet. What I have tried;

1)

```
Execute
('Select * From @TempTable
Pivot(Max(myReturns) For ID In (' + @InString + ')) As myPTable')
```

Result:  `error must declare @TempTable  - table out of scope`

2) Then changed `@TempTable` to `#TempTable`;
Prints as:

```
Select * From #TempTable
Pivot(Max(myReturns) For ID In (1,2,3)) As myPTable
```

When execute that, I get error:  `Incorrect syntax near '1'`

Which leads me to think the `ID`'s should be delimited as `[1],[2],[3]`..

Earlier I have also tried executing with the normal `execute`, but also the `Exec sp_executesql`

Comment: As far as your second attempt that returns an incorrect syntax - since your columns are numeric, then you need to surround each column with a square bracket (i.e., `[1], [2], [3]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to do this

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000) = 'Select * From @ReturnsTable Pivot(Max(myReturns) For [ID] In (' 
     + @InString+ ') As myPTable'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

It **won't work**

This is because your `@returnsTable` is in the scope of your code, and your dynamic SQL will be in a different scope. If you want to pass a table variable to the dynamic SQL, you need to make it a defined type, and pass it as a parameter.

See [using Table variable with sp_executesql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329996/using-table-variable-with-sp-executesql)

If you can use a temporary `#table` instead of a table variable, dynamic SQL will work.

Comment: With using the #Table, I also wrote a small function which delimits everything between brackets of @Instring, then the dynamic SQL works

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE  @InString varchar(50)='1,2,3,4'
```

USE `Print` statement first so you confirm that you are executing correct query dynamically

```
PRINT 
'Select * From @ReturnsTable 
Pivot(
Max(myReturns) 
For [ID] In (' + @InString+ ') As myPTable'
```

Output

```
Select * From @ReturnsTable 
Pivot(
Max(myReturns) 
For [ID] In (1,2,3,4) As myPTable
```

When you sure the print is correct then execute it by using `EXECUTE`

```
EXECUTE(
'Select * From @ReturnsTable 
Pivot(
Max(myReturns) 
For [ID] In (' + @InString+ ') As myPTable'
)
```