# Select into table from dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to select into table variable from `@query`.

Here is `@query`:

```
SELECT @QUERY = 'SELECT DISTINCT USER_KEY, (SELECT TOP(1) USER_FNM  FROM BAUSER WHERE BAUSER.USER_KEY = PIVOT_LOCATIONS.USER_KEY), ' + @COLDEPSUMMARY + '
FROM CAUSDE_TAS 
PIVOT
(
SUM(USDE_HSU)
FOR DEPA_KEY IN (' + @COLDEPARTMENTS + ')
) PIVOT_LOCATIONS
WHERE USDE_DAT >= ''' + format(@DATEFROM, 'MM.dd.yyyy') + ''' AND USDE_DAT <= ''' + format(@DATETO, 'MM.dd.yyyy') + ''' 
AND USER_KEY IN (' + @USERS_STR + ')
GROUP BY USER_KEY'


EXECUTE (@QUERY)
```

What I would like to do is get results from `EXECUTE(@QUERY)` and insert those results into temporary `@USERS` table:

```
DECLARE @USERS TABLE
(
  USER_KEY INT,
  USER_FNM VARCHAR(50),
  USDE_HSU DECIMAL(8,2),
  [110000003] DECIMAL(8,2),
[120000002] DECIMAL(8,2),
[120000003] DECIMAL(8,2),
[120000004] DECIMAL(8,2),
[120000005] DECIMAL(8,2),
[120000006] DECIMAL(8,2),
[120000007] DECIMAL(8,2),
[120000008] DECIMAL(8,2)
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL? In this instance, it doesn't appear to be necessary. Without dynamic SQL, you can use the standard `SELECT...INTO` statement.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan - sorry, it is not visible from example, but there are around 80 columns. I am generating them dynamically. (this is part of result from dynamic generation. I haven't pasted all columns, it would be unnecessary complication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
INSERT INTO @USERS
EXECUTE(@QUERY)
```

Given that you have made all proper declarations in advance.

Example:

```
declare @something table (
 someint int
)

declare @query varchar(max);

select @query = 'select 1
union all
select 2';

insert into @something (someint)
execute(@query)

select * from @something
```

Yields

```
 someint
       1
       2
```

Comment: What if table has some columns that query is not returning? Should table and query always has the same columns? I mean - is there a way of returning e.g. NULL into column which is not part of query, but it is part of table?

Comment: As you see in my example, I specify which columns to insert into. It works just as a normal insert into with values procured by query..

Answer (score 0):

If you switch your table variable to a temporary table, you can insert into it from within the dynamic SQL in the same batch. This avoids the possible future error listed in the next section.

```
CREATE TABLE #USERS (...);

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    INSERT #USERS (USER_KEY, ...)
    SELECT USER_KEY, ' + @COLDEPSUMMARY + N', ...';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@DATEFROM DATE, @DATETO DATE, ...', @DATEFROM, @DATETO, ...;
```

You'll also notice I used [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead. [It's generally a bad practice to use `EXEC` instead of `sp_executesql`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql). You won't be able to use parameters for the dynamic column portion, but you can at least use it to pass in the other parameters such as `@DATEFROM` and `@DATETO`. [You can also pass your other parameter `@USERS_STR` if you convert to a table type beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7330410/1409101).

---

As previously mentioned, I suggest against using `INSERT....EXEC` where possible as it can eventually result in the following error if you have nested stored procedures both using it:

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1
>
> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

Example:

```
CREATE PROC #Test1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #Test1 ( A INT );

    INSERT #Test1
    EXEC('SELECT 1')
END;
GO
CREATE PROC #Test2
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #Test2 ( B INT );

    INSERT #Test2
    EXEC #Test1
END;
GO
EXEC #Test2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use table-functions as example:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_Some_Table] (
    @Id int
)

RETURNS @tbResults TABLE (
    uId uniqueidentifier,
    sType VARCHAR(5),
    sCode VARCHAR(50)
)

AS

BEGIN

    -- select, insert into, create various @tables ecc...

    RETURN

END

GO
```

Then use:

```
INSERT INTO @tb (uId, sType, sCode) SELECT uId,sType,sCode FROM dbo.Get_Same_Table(@id)
```

**This prevents NESTED INSERT EXEC** and uses the same lines of code.
Hope this helps, see you!