# How to update a local table variable using dynamically generated column name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have some aggregated data :

```
name   asd  colA   ColB    ColC      X      Y
-----------------------------------------------
...
George  PJ  Sp      P       B       14.8    56
George  PJ  Sp      P       C       11.4    43
...
-----------------------------------------------
```

And a local result table

```
declare @result table(
    Name nvarchar(255),
    SP_E_A int null,
    SP_E_B int null,
    SP_E_C int null,
    SP_E_D int null,
    SP_E_viso decimal(5,1) null,
    ...
    --LOTS MORE COLUMN GOES AFTER
    ...
)
```

*It has **lots** of columns*

What I'm trying to do is :
generate an update statement dynamically and execute it
Example:

```
UPDATE TABLE @table SET SP_P_B = 56
```

So I wrote this

```
open cursor for *that result set*
declare @sql varchar(255) = 'UPDATE @table SET '+@colA+'_'+@colB+'_'+@colC+'='+CONVERT(varchar,@Y);
exec (@sql)
```

Error I'm getting

> Must declare the table variable "@table".

Looks like exec starts another session where @result table doesn't exist.

How can I work around it ?

Comment: just change to use temp table.

Comment: @Squirrel should I use local, global or tempDb ?

Comment: Passing table variables in/out of dynamic SQL statements can be tricky.  The issue here is that the dynamic SQL executes within a different context.  This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258798/pass-a-table-variable-to-sp-executesql) shows how you can work around that.

Comment: @destination-data I'm not sure passing a table as parameter will work for me performance-wise (I expect it to degrade a lot if I pass around huge table for so many times, am I mistaking?)

Comment: local temp table `#temp` will do the job

Comment: @Squirrel `Invalid object name '#table'.`

Comment: Certainly it requires more effort upfront, than switching to a temp table (which is the approach I'd probably take).  Performance wise the best way to tell is by trying both.  Comparing the execution times and query plans will show you the way to go.  On performance, as @SeanLange pointed out, removing the cursor would probably provide the biggest boost.

Comment: did you create the `#table` ? change your `declare @table` line  to `create table #table`

Comment: can you post your query ?

Comment: Lol just noticed `create table ##table` and `insert into ##result` don't match. It works

Comment: you don't need to use global temp table. Local temp table will works also.

Comment: You're right. Thanks alot @Squirrel

Comment: Be careful if you are using a global temp table. They have some serious challenges when it comes to concurrency. If there is even the slightest chance more than 1 person will ever be executing this code at the same time you need to rethink this. And for heaven's sake using a cursor for updates is a recipe for horrible performance and maintenance.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the tips, although I'm not using this to `update [AdventureWorks2012].[Sales]`. It's a specific case, several ways to work around, and I choose generating statements instead of a kilometer-long `CASE WHEN(...` because that would be *even worse* maintainance nightmare if business logic changes or I make a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a global Temporary table as the following code shows:

```
CREATE TABLE ##globalSession ( column1 int null, column2 varchar(45) null);

INSERT INTO ##globalSession (column1, column2) Values (2, 'initial data');

declare @sql VARCHAR(255) = 'UPDATE ##globalSession set column1 = 1, column2 = ''test'' ; ';

exec (@sql)

SELECT * FROM ##globalSession

DROP TABLE ##globalSession;
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the must declare the table as @table

Comment: It's not a must, it's just the way I tried. Looks like global temp table will work for me