# Using table variable with dynamic fields as input for dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I want to use a table in a dynamic query. But columns of table are not fixed and they may change.

```
declare @t table(ID int, Fname varchar(50), Lname varchar(50)); -- Columns may change
insert into @t(ID, Fname, Lname)
values
(1, 'Jack', 'Martinez'),
(2, 'Alex', 'Desoza');
```

I have tried below code:

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(max) = '@t'
declare @query nvarchar(max) = 'select * from '+ @tablename 
exec sp_executesql @query
```

But the only thing I get is :

> Must declare the scalar variable "@t".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a TABLE variable to sp\_executesql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258798/pass-a-table-variable-to-sp-executesql)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring the definition of your table variable into 'dynamic' part of the code:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max) = '
declare @t table(ID int, Fname varchar(50), Lname varchar(50));
insert into @t(ID, Fname, Lname)
values
(1, ''Jack'', ''Martinez''),
(2, ''Alex'', ''Desoza'');
select * from @t' 
exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: This poses the question of why use a dynamic statement at all though, when the statement is no longer dynamic.

Comment: It's a good point @Larnu. The list of the columns in table variable declaration as well as values in INSERT column can be populated dynamically.